# How to read the logos and image in the Email using Java where the content of Email is html/Plain text

Tags: java, image, html-parsing, jakarta-mail

I want validate the logo of Facebook, Instagram and other social network in the email footer where the type of email content is "text/html" .

Comment: Wat have you tried already? Do you have any code written yet? Can you provide us with more info so we can help you better?

Comment: Hi, I have tried and get the content of Email by extracting the text from HTML content-type. Hence i get extracted the content of the Email where Logos & Image are excluded in the process of doing that. Therefore I need to read/ get the Image and Logos in the Email by using the JavaMailAPI and java? Do anyone have idea of how to get the Image and Logo in the emails.

Answer (score 0):

If there are images in HTML then they must be sourced, you need to follow the source. In my view, you should write simple data **scraper** for plain html in email to get image source and follow that to get image. This would be worked only for html in-line images. For attachments, you need to write get file methods.